# how to setup printing points in C# printing

Tags: c#

My printing form contains many printing place. I want to pass the textbox text to correct places in printing document. I am using (pixels) to mention the printing points.

```
g.DrawString("Total", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(40, 160));
g.DrawString(": ", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Blue, new Point(150, 160));
```

Measurements is in cm and is converted to pixels. But it is not placed in the correct position.

What are my options to have better control over the measurement units?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default setting for the [`PageUnit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.pageunit(v=vs.110).aspx) on your Graphics instance will be [`Display`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphicsunit(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Specifies the unit of measure of the display device. Typically pixels for video displays, and 1/100 inch for printers.

So without changing anything a Point on the Graphics instance of a PrinterDocument depicts 1/100 of an inch.

With this info a possible solution would be to introduce helper methods calculate inches to 1/100 of an inch and centimeters to inch.

```
    public static PointF FromCm(float cmx, float cmy)
    {
        const float cm2inch = 1/2.54F;
        return FromInch(cmx * cm2inch, cmy * cm2inch);
    }

    public static PointF FromInch(float inchx, float inchy)
    {
        return new PointF(inchx * 100, inchy * 100);
    }
```

And use it like so:

```
        g.DrawString(
            "Total", 
            new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), 
            Brushes.Black, 
            FromCm(1,1));
```

The [GraphicsUnit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphicsunit(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration does have a setting for `Millimeter`.

```
        g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;

        g.DrawString(
           "Total",
           new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular),
           Brushes.Black,
           new PointF(25 , 10)); // due to millimeter 
                                 // setting this is now 2,5 cm and 1 cm
```

You can switch the `PageUnit` at any moment during the paint process. So you can mix and match whatever Unit of measurement is convenient.

Comment: Graphics g = ppev.Graphics;
            g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
g.DrawString(" " + textBox1.Text, new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new PointF(12,26));
I am using like this on my code bt its not printing in correct point. I don't no what is the problem is